# What are the individual Color Ids?

Tags: diep.io

Recently, there has been a console addition to [diep.io](http://diep.io). I know that there is a way to change the colour individual components of [diep.io](http://diep.io), but I don't know how to do so completely. All it mentions when I type `help` is `net_replace_color [id][hex]`. I already know how to change the color using hexadecimal, but I don't what each individual `id` is.

For example:

- 1 = Tank??
- 2 = Turret??

Comment: Reading the [Wiki for the commands](http://diepio.wikia.com/wiki/Console#cite_ref-console1_1-0), it almost sounds like the `id` is the color you want to replace with the hexadecimal number, but that would be kind of odd.

Comment: @TimmyJim The `id` is for the, say `_turret`, or `_tank`, or `_background`

Comment: Oh so you know this for a fact? I thought your example was just guesswork.

Comment: @TimmyTim, The turret and tank _is_ guesswork, but the others not so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I could find so far, a list of IDs can be found on [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Diepio/comments/5xx5cp/replacing_colors/), although one of them appears to be unknown at this point:

> There are 18 changeable colors right now.
>
> - 0: Smasher/Dominator/Auto Smasher/Spike/Landmine base
> - 1: Turrets/barrels
> - 2: You (FFA)
> - 3: Blue team
> - 4: Red team
> - 5: Purple team
> - 6: Green team
> - 7: Shiny Shapes (Green)
> - 8: Squares
> - 9: Triangles
> - 10: Pentagons
> - 11: Crashers
> - 12: Neutral Dominators and Arena Closers
> - 13: Leaderboard (FFA)
> - 14: Maze walls
> - 15: Others (FFA)
> - 16: Controlled/Necromancer squares (FFA)
> - 17: Fallen team (Fallen Booster and Fallen Overlord)
> - 18: ???
>
> All team colors including Others and You from FFA include bullets and bases as well.

Color ID `18` does not change anything that is displayed, as explained by [a comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Diepio/comments/5xx5cp/replacing_colors/deom5du/) on the post:

> 18 doesn't do anything since it's default value is 000021 (which isn't a diep.io color).

Comment: I don't use reddit, but thanks in advance. Unfortunately, I only give votes after 24 hours _or_ There are more than two posts.

Comment: We've actually figured out 7: it's green/shiny shapes.

Comment: @haykam , what is 18? I'll accept it anyway but I still need 18

Comment: We're still looking for 18. I'll update this post when we can confirm which color is 18.